# Installing PhantomJS in CentOS

Tags: centos, phantomjs, installation

I am trying to install PhantomJS in Centos. These are the steps I followed.

```
yum install freetype fontconfig
cd ~
wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-i686.tar.bz2
bunzip2 phantomjs*.tar.bz2
tar xvf phantomjs*.tar
cp phantomjs*/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

I'm getting this below error.

```
phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone throw some light. I have installed fontconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that version is ancient, Do you need it for a specific reason?

Anyway, [a basic Google search](https://www.google.ru/search?q=libfontconfig.so.1%3A+cannot+open+shared+object+centos) of your error [suggests installing](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10904) an additional package:

```
libfontconfig
```

Comment: I was following steps from some blogs. Do you have the steps to install the latest version. Thanks !

Comment: Try https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-i686.tar.bz2

Comment: No package libfontconfig available for centos

Comment: Could be libfontconfig1 or some similar, you could Google the error together with your CentOs version.

Answer (score 0):

No package libfontconfig available for centos.
You could try installing it manually:

```
wget http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/release/fontconfig-2.11.0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf fontconfig-2.11.0.tar.gz
cd fontconfig-2.11.0
./configure -prefix=/usr
make
# move the file into /usr/lib manually (don't trust 'make install' on a production box)
sudo mv ./src/.libs/libfontconfig.so.1.2.0 /usr/lib/
# and setup the libfontconfig.so.1 symlink
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s libfontconfig.so.1.2.0 libfontconfig.so.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me on Amazon Linux 2018.03. (While not exactly the same, Amazon Linux is similar to RedHat / Centos)

```
yum install fontconfig freetype freetype-devel fontconfig-devel libstdc++
```

Answer (score 0):

anyone who is struggling with installing phantomJS on CentOS with ES6 support.
Follow the following steps.

Install Wine on CentOS **(Wine lets you run windows .exe applications on linux distributions)** 
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-wine-on-centos

Download this package
https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.5.0-beta2-windows.zip

```
wine64 phantomjs.exe script.js
```

Its that simple. Enjoy.

I have tested it with CentOS 6 and 7